# Alone, a part of a regex works. With a part added before it and an other after it, it stops working

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

UPDATE: I'm making progress, but this is hard!

The test text will be `valid[REGEX_EMAIL|REGEX_PASSWORD|REGEX_TEST]`.

(The real life text is `required|valid[REGEX_EMAIL]|confirmed[emailconfirmation]|correct[not in|emailconfirmation|email confirmation]`.)

`([^|]+)` saves REGEX_EMAIL, REGEX_PASSWORD and REGEX_TEST in an array.

`^[^[]+\[` matches valid[

`\]` matches ]

`^[^[]+\[` + `([^|]+)` + `\]` doesn't save REGEX_EMAIL, REGEX_PASSWORD and REGEX_TEST in an array.

How to solve?

Comment: The other question: match everything, except for [, ] and everything between [ and ]. This question: between [ and ], split the string using | as delimiter into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is it important to try to everything with a single regular expression? It becomes much easier if you extract the two parts first and then split the strings on `|` using explode:

```
$s = 'valid[REGEX_EMAIL|REGEX_PASSWORD|REGEX_TEST]';
$matches = array();
$s = preg_match('/^([^[]++)\[([^]]++)\]$/', $s, $matches);
$left = explode('|', $matches[1]);
$right = explode('|', $matches[2]);
print_r($left);
print_r($right);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => valid
)
Array
(
    [0] => REGEX_EMAIL
    [1] => REGEX_PASSWORD
    [2] => REGEX_TEST
)
```

Comment: it's really like you've said it! `(?:c(a)t)+` for catcat saves the second a only :-( ++ is too advanced, I still don't understand atomic grouping :-(

Comment: You can replace ++ with + and it will give you the exact same result.